# «В этом пузырьке (—) простые, чёрные чернила, а в том — химические, фиолетовые»

Tags: пунктуация, тире

Нужно ли тире после "пузырьке"? Если не нужно, то почему?

Answer (score 2):

**В этом пузырьке** [находятся] **простые, чёрные чернила, а в том** [пузырьке находятся] **— химические, фиолетовые.**
Это предложение из пособия Д. Э. Розенталя.

Он же в справочнике по русскому языку разъясняет, что тире ставится при ***наличии паузы*** в так называемых эллиптических предложениях (самостоятельно употребляемых предложениях с отсутствующим сказуемым): *За калиткой — третий плац, строевой, необыкновенной величины* (Куприн).
При отсутствии паузы тире в эллиптическом предложении не ставится: *Вдруг передо мною рытвина глубокая* (Лермонтов).

Так что выбор — ставить или не ставить тире? — за пишущим. В этом предложении автор посчитал, что паузы нет (поэтому нет и тире).

[Пособие по русскому языку с упражнениями. Для поступающих в вузы](https://books.google.ee/books?id=f5e8DwAAQBAJ&pg=PA202&lpg=PA202&dq=%E2%80%9C%D0%92%20%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%20%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%B7%D1%8B%D1%80%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B5%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B5,%20%D1%87%D1%91%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5%20%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0,%20%D0%B0%20%D0%B2%20%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%20-%20%D1%85%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5,%20%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B5&source=bl&ots=Ppsyia1yIo&sig=ACfU3U00fUkZ5zaw4Cqy8uEP9PoPg5S8dQ&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjRxbj2_oPyAhViwosKHcPUCT0Q6AEwDHoECBIQAw#v=onepage&q=%E2%80%9C%D0%92%20%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%20%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%B7%D1%8B%D1%80%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B5%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B5%2C%20%D1%87%D1%91%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5%20%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0%2C%20%D0%B0%20%D0%B2%20%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%20-%20%D1%85%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5%2C%20%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B5&f=false)
[Тире в неполном предложении](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=91#pp91)

Answer (score 1):

Помнится, такой пример приводился у Розенталя, правда, относился он к однородным определениям. А что касается тире, то здесь классический пример неполного предложения, в котором на месте пропущенных сказуемых ставится тире.